# How do leased lines work?

Tags: networking

I don't know any site where to ask this... sorry:

I am trying to understand the telephone system and as I went through the information I stumbled over an internet-access-option called "leased line".
As a beginner, its often not that easy to understand how it works. It would be GREAT if you could give me an overall picture of what this is and how it works (you can dig in a bit deeper...), what the commmon speed is and how good it is compared to DSL!

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Part 1: [Wikipedia Leased line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leased_line). Part 2: what metric do you have in mind for comparing it to DSL?

Comment: speed, cost, easiness to install it

Comment: This is pretty off topic here, but a "leased line" is an extremely generic term for a point to point link of some kind, it could be physical (a dedicated copper or fiber link between two locations) or virtual... It can range from 9600bps to 10's or even 100's of gigabits per second, and the interface could be anything from RS-232, T-1, Ethernet, Fiber, or anything. The term is too generic to provide an answer outside of what wikipedia or other online resources could easily provide.

Comment: Thanks, this gave me a great insight! And I didn't really know where to ask this question...

Comment: You should post your question at [NetworkEngineering Stackex](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) for better answers.

Comment: A leased line is typically more reliable, more consistent and a lot more expensive then a DSL connection as leased lines are dedicated resources, while DSL infrastructure is shared. It is typically (but not always) slower.

Answer (score 2):

There are two major differences between a lease line and a regular internet connection. (Maybe more that I can't remember at the moment)

1. Leased lines have a guaranteed bandwidth through SLA. (service level agreement) depending on the network type the leased line is offered over, it may also have a latency/jitter guarantee. common residential and Soho connections have no guarantee on bandwidth or latency, and have no uptime guarantee, or problem resolution turn around guarantee.
2. Soho and residential connections are just a pipe to the internet. Leased lines can be purchased to have a PVC (permanent virtual circuit) created from two locations (usually branch offices). Connections that are considered a PVC are alot like a private VLAN through the ISP's switched network. To the equipment on either side, it's the equivalent of having a Ethernet cord stretching through the internet to the other branch office. The equipment on each side doesn't know the difference.

Leased lines are considerably more expensive than regular internet connections. This has to do with the uptime and service level guarantees.

Comment: Leased lines also appear as a point-to-point connection.

Comment: @davidgo Ah, right you are. I knew I was forgetting something.

Answer (score -1):

A leased line is one line only used by one customer.  DSL shares the line with others through frequency differences between the customers.
Forget a leased line, they are too expensive.  Mostly used by businesses.
Home users get DSL, much cheaper.  The best for cost and speed is fiber, then coax.

Comment: The best argument for leased lines is ... that its dedicated right?

Comment: @Dan this is simply wrong. A DSL connection is 1 or more pairs (normally 1) between the connection and exchange/cabinet - no sharing. Cable shares a single line I believe. Also, a "typical" (analog) leased line is a "pots" line which only samples the voice spectrum - about 30-8000z of frequency (at 8bits at a frequency of 8000 times per second= 64k), while DSL breaks the line up into multiple frequency ranges which it combines for more speed. thanks